# User:index is undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I have made a localStorage with a user_name login and i have parsed the string of my JSON data (entry) to a plain object.

But if I try to console log entry.username i get my stored users but also get a "undefined"?

I suspect that is my User:index code that is messing up the entry.user_name?

```
var User = {
    index: window.localStorage.getItem("User:index"),
    $form: document.getElementById("userReg"),


    $button_register: document.getElementById("registerUser"),
    $button_login: document.getElementById("logIN"),

    init: function() {
        // initialize storage index
        if (!User.index) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("User:index", User.index = 1);
        }

        User.$form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
            var entry = {
                id: parseInt(this.id_entry.value),
                user_name: this.user_name.value,
            };
            if (entry.id == 0) {
                User.storeAdd(entry);
            }
        }, true);


        User.$button_login.addEventListener("click", function(entry) {

            for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
                var key = localStorage.key(i);
                var value = localStorage[key];
                entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
                console.log(entry.user_name);
            }

            if (document.getElementById("firstName").value == entry.user_name) {
                alert("You have logged in");

            } else {
                document.getElementById("negative").innerHTML = "Username does not match"
            }


        }, true);


    },

    storeAdd: function(entry) {
        entry.id = User.index;
        window.localStorage.setItem("User:index", ++User.index);
        window.localStorage.setItem("User:" + entry.id, JSON.stringify(entry));
    },


};



User.init();
```

Comment: can you show us the HTML and tell us what you click / type? Maybe make a fiddle

Comment: Also seems like the index is read as a field from local storage before you assign a value in the init method.  Have you tried only reading the value if one has been assigned?  So your init would set the index = 1 the first time through.  Why read the potentially undefined value and add 1 to it?

Comment: @LoganMurphy [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yv04x4mw/2/)

Comment: @xDaevax not quite sure what you mean should i assign a value to the index after init method...or can you give an example?

Comment: Upon further investigation, your loop is what seems to be part of the problem.  Your index is always n+1 (due to the `User:index` local storage entry), but in your loop you don't account for this fact.  Given 3 elements in local storage + `User:index`, your iterator limit will be 4 in your for loop, which on the last index gives `undefined` because the localStorage[4] is `User:index` and not a user entry so the JSON parse will fail and give you the undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right it is the User:index causing this issue. You can fix it with the following code.

```
for(var i = 1; i < User.index; i++) {
    var key = "User:" + i;
    var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
    console.log("entry : ", key, entry);
    ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yv04x4mw/6/

May I also recommend not creating accounts this way (unless you have a good reason), also use a JavaScript library like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the data in localStorage.  Your login function assumes that all entries stored in localStorage will be of your `User` entry type.  But when you start storing other things, you have no checking to confirm the type is what you expect.

Here:

```
        for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i) {
            var key = localStorage.key(i);
            var value = localStorage[key];
            entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
            console.log(entry.user_name);
        }
```

The line that is actually failing is: `entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));` because at the end of the loop, the type in localStorage is `User:index`, not `User:3`.

If you plan on having more things in localStorage, you should add a check in your loop, such as this:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; ++i) {
            var key = localStorage.key(i);
            var reg = new RegExp("User\:\\d+$");
            //Only process user entries
            if(reg.test(key)) {

                var value = localStorage[key];
                entry = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
                console.log(entry.user_name);
                console.log(entry);
            } // end if
        }
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/Lo63vftt/

*Disclaimer*: I changed some other things to in order for it to work more efficiently for a fiddle, you can ignore the other changes I made.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain the reasoning so I can improve the answer?

Comment: the order of keys in the localstorage might not necessarily map to the `i` variable for the loop therefore you may never pass the boolean test in the `if`.

Comment: since the keys are alphabetical 1, 10, 11, 2, 3, 4, 5...but i is numberical 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: and there could be some intermediate keys

Comment: I see your point.  As far as the alphabetical goes however, all of my debugging revealed the items were stored in the order in which they were added (so numerical is fine) but if an item is stored in between user elements that would be a problem.  That's what I get for being lazy and skipping a Regex key check.  I will modify my answer shortly.

Comment: its definitely ordered until 10 gets in there...i look forward to your modification

Comment: Thanks to both of you will try to test it out! (and yes know it's a bad solution but it is for a school project)... @xDaevax dunno only have 5 reputation (15 for votes)

Comment: @LoganMurphy  I have updated my fiddle and my answer with correct matching code.  Thanks for identifying the issue in my response.

Comment: @LoganMurphy you mentioned using jQuery - i have tried making a modul with Twitter Bootstrap and adding the script external.  But it now says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null any idea?

Comment: If you started using jQuery your code would look something like the  code in this link http://jsfiddle.net/thm1bjjf/ then make the changes i suggested. Perhaps you should ask another question and link it here.

Comment: @LoganMurphy I am learning some jQuery on the side - but have a question regarding editing localStorage [Edit User Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26160759/edit-localstorage-user) if you have time